# Facebook API batch likes request

Tags: ruby, facebook

I'm trying to get the like count for multiple urls at once with Ruby. I've tried something like this but it does not seem to work:

```
batch_get = [{"method"=>"GET", "relative_url"=>"method/fql.query?query=select total_count from link_stat where url='http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-26233909'"}, {"method"=>"GET", "relative_url"=>"method/fql.query?query=select total_count from link_stat where url='http://english.chosun.com/site/data/html_dir/2014/02/19/2014021900954.html'"}]

q = "select total_count from link_stat where url='#{batch_get}'"
fbreq = URI.escape("https://graph.facebook.com/?batch=#{q}")
JSON.parse(open(fbreq).read)
```

I am able to get single url likes but the performance is quite bad, I'd like to get them in one request. Is this feasible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to batch this, it can be done via a single FQL query:

```
select url, total_count from link_stat where url in ('http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-26233909','http://english.chosun.com/site/data/html_dir/2014/02/19/2014021900954.html')
```

So, the request would be

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select+url%2C+total_count+from+link_stat+where+url+in+%28%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bbc.co.uk%2Fnews%2Fworld-us-canada-26233909%27%2C%27http%3A%2F%2Fenglish.chosun.com%2Fsite%2Fdata%2Fhtml_dir%2F2014%2F02%2F19%2F2014021900954.html%27%29&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Comment: Keep in mind that FQL now is deprecated for facebook api v2.1+

Comment: That's true, but by the time of writing the answer it wasn't. Furthermore, if you have a v2.0 app, you can use FQL until August 7th 2016.